# Angular 11 Only 1 library in Lazy chunk files when ng build

Tags: angular, angular11, angular-lazyloading

I have a two libraries that are built into `node_modules` directory. I use `libray1` in `library2` and use both in `app-routing.module.ts` to lazy load routes in both libraries. When I ng build the main app, It shows only `library2` under Lazy chunk files.

```
Initial Chunk Files | Names         |      Size
vendor.js           | vendor        |   3.46 MB
styles.css          | styles        | 176.72 kB
polyfills.js        | polyfills     | 136.13 kB
main.js             | main          |  10.84 kB
runtime.js          | runtime       |   9.00 kB
                    | Initial Total |   3.78 MB

Lazy Chunk Files    | Names         |      Size
library2.js    | library2 |  35.98 kB
```

Here is `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('library1').then(m => m.AccountRoutingModule)
  }, {
    path: 'cars',
    loadChildren: () => import('library2').then(m => m.CarRoutingModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I can't figure out why this is the case. I suspected it might be caused by importing `library1` module in `library2` but I checked out and build result does not change. Anyone can point me to the right direction about why this is happening?

Comment: why are you loading routing module in loadChildren?

Comment: @zainhassan I did that to lazily load the children routes. I  recently changed it to main modules like 'CarModule' but the output did not change. Do you have any idea about what should I do?

Comment: Make sure you have not imported modules in loadchildren anywhere else

Comment: Yes that was it, I was importing something from library1 in `app.component.ts`. Thanks for the pointer.